# Conditionally include maven dependency locally instead of nexus repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I have a project A and B. Project B uses project A as a dependency. I am publishing project A to Nexus repository when changes are tested and good to go to Nexus. However I don't want to publish project A to nexus whenever I want to test changes locally.

Is there a way to use project A's changes locally into project B without having it to be read from repository. Some condition that will make maven read project A from local rather than Nexus.

I want to keep project A in common maven dependencies rather than making changes in Maven profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing some obvious point but I would assume that you can just `mvn install` project A with a new `version` and adjust the `dependency` of A in project B to use that new version. By installing project A it should be available to be used in project B locally because it will be installed into your local Maven repository.

E.g.
In project A's pom.xml

```
<project>
    <name>A</name>
    <version>1.1.1-new-version-for-testing</version>
</project>
```

In project B's pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1-new-version-for-testing</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, there is a local repository on your computer that contains all the dependencies (by default in ~/.m2 but you can change that)
You can think about it as a local cache of the dependencies required to work with your own project

When you change the project A you can install the "updated" version by running `mvn install` on project A.

After that command project B when tested will not try to contact maven repository and will get a version of project A from your local repository.

For SNAPSHOT dependencies, maven once in a day will try to get the later version from Nexus anyway, even if you have a copy in the local repository, because working with snapshots assumes that you're OK with getting daily changes.

But then you have the following choices:

1. Don't work with SNAPSHOT-s at all. This is something that you shouldn't do anyway in production (I mean, when you release project B, it should contain SNAPSHOT dependencies in its pom)
2. When you compile project B, assuming you have all the dependencies in the local repository, use `mvn <whatever> -o`. This `-o` option means that maven should be run in offline mode, that is it won't attempt to contact a remote repository altogether. (BTW, If you want to do the opposite, which is to forcefully download all new dependencies from Nexus, you can run `mvn <whatever> -U`